# Can oral contraceptives prevent ovarian cysts from forming?

Tags: medications, contraception, gynecology

I wanted to know if there are any ways or any preventive measure that a female can take to prevent the formation of ovarian cyst. In many websites I found that using oral contraceptives prevents the formation of ovarian cyst.

Now, is it logical/healthy to take oral contraceptives on a regular basis even if one is not using them as birth control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [I]s it logical/healthy to take in oral contraceptives on a regular basis even if one is not engaged in intercourse?

There are several reasons to take oral contraceptive pills (OCPs) that have nothing to do with contraception. In that way, they can be considered medications to treat medical conditions, not contraceptives.

In the case of women who bleed heavily during their periods, or those have their periods too frequently or irregularly, OCP's can reduce the amount of bleeding preventing anemia and can "regulate" cycles.

When a woman has [excessive pain with menstruation](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/975/), OCPs can decrease the pain significantly. If women suffer from debilitating premenstrual dysphoric disorder symptoms (aka PMS), OCP help considerably.

OCPs have been used to treat acne, hirsutism (excessive body hair, especially facial), and significant menstrual-related migraines.

In women with premature menopause, OCP's can decrease the risk of endometrial and ovarian cancer.

Interestingly, OCPs are not considered a good treatment of functional ovarian cysts, though intuitively one would think they were.

> Most patients are unaware of these health benefits and therapeutic uses of oral contraceptives, and they tend to overestimate their risk. Counseling and education are necessary to help women make well-informed health-care decisions ...

As with any medication, discussion about the risks of OCP use should take place with the prescribing physician, and in the case of the benefits outweighing the risks, the choice to treat the condition with OCPs is quite logical.

<sub>[Noncontraceptive benefits and therapeutic uses of the oral contraceptive pill.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11727171)</sub>
<sub>[ACOG Guidelines on Noncontraceptive Uses of Hormonal Contraceptives](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2010/0801/p288.html)</sub>
<sub>[Hormonal treatment of functional ovarian cysts: a randomized, prospective study.](http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/2226910)</sub>
<sub>[Consensus on infertility treatment related to polycystic ovary syndrome](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0015028207036618)</sub>
<sub>[Effect of Long-Term Treatment with Metformin Added to Hypocaloric Diet on Body Composition, Fat Distribution, and Androgen and Insulin Levels in Abdominally Obese Women with and without the Polycystic Ovary Syndrome](http://press.endocrine.org/doi/abs/10.1210/jcem.85.8.6738)</sub>