# Do tampons cause menstrual pain?

Tags: pain, gynecology, menstrual-cycle, tampons, dysmenorrhea

I heard that from the pressure of tampons used during menstruation, women can get lower abdominal pain. What are the causes that lead from pressure to pain. Does this pain increase with different sizes of tampon?

---

As lined out by era the broader question [Is there anything anyone can do to decrease the symptoms of dysmenorrhea?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/975/is-there-anything-anyone-can-do-to-decrease-the-symptoms-of-dysmenorrhea) is a good place to start reading. Besides: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysmenorrhea

Comment: First, welcome to Health.SE.  For questions with common knowledge, it's better to some general reading first, ie [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysmenorrhea), and then come back with questions on points that weren't clear.  As it is, I'm a little confused as to your question between the title and then the tampon question.

Comment: Are you referring to _stomach pain_ (unusual menstrual symptom) or _lower abdominal pain_ (much more common)? This is really broad right now, unless your question is simply "are there causes of menstrual pain besides tampon use."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anything anyone can do to decrease the symptoms of dysmenorrhea?](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/975/is-there-anything-anyone-can-do-to-decrease-the-symptoms-of-dysmenorrhea)

Comment: It's fine to edit a question. But it's generally frowned upon on SE sites to *change* a question once it's gotten an answer. I'll edit my answer, but please be aware that the norm is to ask a new question when this happens.

Comment: alright, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume by "stomach", you mean abdominal pain, probably lower abdominal pain. And yes, tampons can cause lower abdominal pain in the presence of endometriosis (ectopic endometrial tissue). The symptoms of endometriosis can include pain on micturition, defecation, tampon or diaphragm insertion, increased pain with menses, intercourse, etc.

Use of tampons in healthy females is generally well-tolerated.

Edited to address OP's edit:

Tampons are generally well tolerated by healthy, normal females. However, there are groups of females that do find tampon use uncomfortable, chief among them adolescents. For this reason, physicians often speak with adolescents at menarche about tampon use.

> With regard to comfort, girls often choose tampons of too high absorbency. Highly absorbent tampons may cause discomfort in young girls because of their larger size or because of a drying effect during wear and upon withdrawal. Advise your patient to choose the lowest tampon absorbency for her needs by experimenting with a pad or pantiliner for backup protection. Less absorbent products can be used on lighter days. This guidance is also consistent with the Food and Drug Administration’s current recommendations for reducing the risk of menstrual toxic shock syndrome.

In other words, young girls should use smaller tampons. Pain with tampon use in this age group is more likely and in some cases can lead to problems with pain later on.

<sub>[Relation between pain symptoms and the anatomic location of deep infiltrating endometriosis](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0015028202033319)</sub>
<sub>[Prevalence and predictors of chronic lower genital tract discomfort](http://www.ajog.org/article/S0002-9378%2801%2979155-7/abstract) Small self-reported study</sub>
<sub>Menstruation in young girls: a clinical perspective, Obstetrics & Gynecology, Vol 4., 2002</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I learned a lot. Especially many english medical terms.

Comment: A good answer to a sensible question. Thanks everyone :-)